# How avoid __res_querydomain - sendmail compilation problem

Tags: sendmail

During sendmail compilation on Debian (raspberry) I've encountered problem with __res_querydomain  undefinded funtion.
How avoid it?

Answer (score 0):

In sendmail/README is:

"""

```
  Fedora Core 5, 64 bit version
    If the ld stage fails with undefined functions like
    __res_querydomain, __dn_expand
    then add these lines to devtools/Site/site.config.m4

    APPENDDEF(`confLIBDIRS', `-L/usr/lib64')
    APPENDDEF(`confINCDIRS', `-I/usr/include/bind9')

    and rebuild (sh ./Build -c).

    Problem noted by Daniel Krones, solution suggested by
    Anthony Howe.
```

"""

First of all this is not only Fedora Core 5, 64 bit version problem.

In my case that was on Debian.

Real solution is use proper parameter -L for glib library:

on my raspberry it was:

-L/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/

example of compilation comand is:
./Build -c -I/usr/local/include/sasl2/ -L/usr/lib/ -L/usr/lib/sasl2 -L/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/

Answer (score 0):

My mistake

there should be pointed directory of libresolv.

In my case it is the same as glib.